# Javascript 3-Key Maximum with .onkeydown/up Keypress Detection

Tags: javascript, keyboard, max, keypress, onkeypress

When I detect keys being pressed with JavaScript in Mozilla Firefox 22, I am unable to detect any more than 3 keys being pressed when using `document.onkeydown` and `document.onkeyup`, setting each key to either `true` or `false`. My code is:

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
document.onkeyup = checkKeyUp;

function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 87 || e.keyCode == 38) keyW = true
    if (e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 37) keyA = true
    if (e.keyCode == 83 || e.keyCode == 40) keyS = true
    if (e.keyCode == 68 || e.keyCode == 39) keyD = true
}

function checkKeyUp(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 87 || e.keyCode == 38) keyW = false
    if (e.keyCode == 65 || e.keyCode == 37) keyA = false
    if (e.keyCode == 83 || e.keyCode == 40) keyS = false
    if (e.keyCode == 68 || e.keyCode == 39) keyD = false
}

keyW = false
keyA = false
keyS = false
keyD = false
```

But all four of the keys cannot be all set to `true` at the same time by pressing them. There will always be one last one that is `false` and stays that way whether or not it is pressed.

This is because a web browser would not need to detect more than 3 keys at a time ([Ctrl]+[Shift]+[+] for example).

Here is an experiment I made:

http://jsfiddle.net/n5vbm/

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Well, after 2.5 years, it looks like this is no longer an issue. (FF 48.0)